Problem with theorem numbering in beamer
I used the following code
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\undef{\lemma}
\undef{\example}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{lemma}{Foobar}
Foo and bar.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}{Barfoo}
Either bar or foo.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}{Something new}
No, not really.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}{Color?}
Indeed.
\end{example}
\begin{example}{Color?}
Indeed.
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

taken from the answer in the question Beamer: Grouping environment counters
However, I take something weird as output

and warning messages
LaTeX Warning: Command `\thelemma' already defined -- not changed on input line
and similar for example.
Any ideas of what is going wrong?

\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\undef{\lemma}
\undef{\example}
\undef{\thelemma}
\undef{\theexample}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{lemma}{Foobar}
Foo and bar.
\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}{Barfoo}
Either bar or foo.
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}{Something new}
No, not really.
\end{theorem}
\begin{example}{Color?}
Indeed.
\end{example}
\begin{example}{Color?}
Indeed.
\end{example}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



The beamer class, precisely the module beamerbasetheorems.sty defines a bunch of theorem-like environments all as siblings of theorem.
Basically it does
\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}

\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{\translate{Lemma}}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\translate{Example}}

which are those that you're interested in. There is no provision for making these environments independent (there should be, in my opinion). By the way, if sections are “counted”, the main environment is defined by
\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}[section]

If you want independent numbering, load beamer with the notheorems option and define the ones you want.
\documentclass[notheorems]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\newtheorem{theorem}{\translate{Theorem}}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\translate{Lemma}}

\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{lemma}[Foobar]
Foo and bar.
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}[Barfoo]
Either bar or foo.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}[Something new]
No, not really.
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}[Color?]
Indeed.
\end{example}

\begin{example}[Color?]
Indeed.
\end{example}

\end{frame}

\end{document}

By the way, the theorem “title” or attribution should be in brackets, not in braces.

